# How to execute javascript in specifci time in .cs?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

If  i have script like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.gmodules.com/ig/ifr?url=http://hosting.gmodules.com/ig/gadgets/file/100080069921643878012/facebook.xml&amp;up_useNewFB_p=1&amp;up_showPopUp2_p=true&amp;synd=open&amp;w=320&amp;h=500&amp;title=Facebook&amp;border=%23ffffff%7C3px%2C1px+solid+%23999999&amp;output=js"></script>
```

and i wanna to execute this script in specific time in my .cs code how to do this?

Comment: C# code runs on the server side, and that script will be loaded in the client side, in what "specific time" would you like it to run?

Comment: I check on some value in comes from the `db` and then i wanna to execute this script which will create a `gadget` in the required place on my page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string rowTestHide = @"<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.gmodules.com/ig/ifr?url=http://hosting.gmodules.com/ig/gadgets/file/100080069921643878012/facebook.xml&amp;up_useNewFB_p=1&amp;up_showPopUp2_p=true&amp;synd=open&amp;w=320&amp;h=500&amp;title=Facebook&amp;
border=%23ffffff%7C3px%2C1px+solid+%23999999&amp;output=js"></script>";
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"rowTest", rowTestHide);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try out with following code,

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude("MyScript", "<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.gmodules.com/ig/ifr?url=http://hosting.gmodules.com/ig/gadgets/file/100080069921643878012/facebook.xml&amp;up_useNewFB_p=1&amp;up_showPopUp2_p=true&amp;synd=open&amp;w=320&amp;h=500&amp;title=Facebook&amp;border=%23ffffff%7C3px%2C1px+solid+%23999999&amp;output=js"></script>");
```

Answer (score 1):

The only real way to do this at the moment (without using something like [SignalR](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR)) is to implement a polling system.

You will have to have an Ajax call, that makes a request to your server every xxx seconds, using something like:

`window.setTimeout(function(){ /* do ajax request */ }, 5000);`

Which would run every 5 seconds.

If the desired result comes back from the DB, you'll have to then programatically inject the required script block into your page.

take a look at this:
[jQuery AJAX polling for JSON response, handling based on AJAX result or JSON content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406580/jquery-ajax-polling-for-json-response-handling-based-on-ajax-result-or-json-con)