# How to save text in the html text area as draft like gmail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autosave

I want to save the text that is in the html text area using ruby on rails.So please help me in setting it as it is in gmail , when we reply to any email it is saved as draft before we send it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save drafts of form elements, for a simple solution, you can use a "drafts" database table or similar and associate a draft with the logged in user and the field they were filling in.

Something like this would work:

```
user_id    form_element_id    draft_content
1          1                  Half way through typi...
```

You will then need to load the drafts when the logged in user loads the form.

You cant do it properly unless they are logged in users.

Comment: In addition, I think you would want a javascript timer that periodically checks for form changes, and if anything changed posts updates that get saved in that drafts table, and then maybe displays "saved as draft" somewhere on the form.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to checkout this gem https://github.com/rubiety/has_draft which may be a bit easier than doing it manually. Also, as others have said if you want true Gmail style you will need to integrate polling and ajax to check for changes and submit them if necessary.

This SO question may help with the polling/ajax part [jQuery AJAX polling for JSON response, handling based on AJAX result or JSON content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406580/jquery-ajax-polling-for-json-response-handling-based-on-ajax-result-or-json-con)