# How can I read partial results in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is an API endpoint which streams results as it gets them. E.g.:

```
GET /results HTTP/1.1

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type:test/plain
Content-Transfer-Encoding:chunked

C;
{"foo":"bar"}
...10 minutes later...
D;
{"bar":"baz"}
0;
```

Is there any way to get `{"foo":"bar"}` before without waiting ten minutes for the rest of the page to be sent?>

Comment: Yes, by using COMET for example http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)

Comment: @antyrat thats the general name of the idea, but nowhere in that link does it tell me how to implement it in a way that is compatible with this type of endpoint

Comment: Maybe this link will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406580/jquery-ajax-polling-for-json-response-handling-based-on-ajax-result-or-json-con

Comment: @antyrat all of those examples wait for the entire request to be fulfilled before returning the result.

Comment: Not with jQuery afaik.

Comment: @Bergi is there a way without jQuery?

Comment: You can create hidden iframe and check it periodically w/ content's.